# Java: How to have standard input take two queues?

Tags: java, input, queue

I have been trying to figure out how to allow a user to input two separate queues. More specifically, I tried (no success) to have some key event that would terminate the input of one queue and allow me to start inputting the entries of the next queue. Thank you. Happy to say this is my first post!

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
 while (!StdIn.isEmpty())
    {

            double one = StdIn.readDouble();
            a.enqueue(one);

        if (scanner.nextInt() == 0)
    {

                double two = StdIn.readDouble();
                b.enqueue(two);

            }
```

(StdIn is not in the standard Java library)

Comment: What is `StdIn`? What "key event" do you want?

Comment: What are `StdIn`,`a`, and `b`?

Comment: The StdIn class provides static methods for reading strings and numbers from standard input. a and b are queues already declared. regarding key event, I just need something that would signal the end of queue a

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the "key event" is a zero value, you'd do it like this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
Queue<Double> a = new ArrayDeque<>();
Queue<Double> b = new ArrayDeque<>();
while (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
    double value = scanner.nextDouble();
    if (value == 0)
        break;
    a.add(value);
}
while (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
    b.add(scanner.nextDouble());
}
```

You can apply the key event check to the second loop too, if you want.

Note that any non-double input will stop the input processing for both queues, and continue with whatever code is after the second `while` loop.

Comment: Ah this is helpful.. a related question: if I want to fill the queue entries and have the queue manipulated by the program's objects, where in the program should I do it? I tried in the main method but got the error "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context" Thanks!

Comment: @Hamza Not seeing your code, I cannot say, besides that's a different question. Create a new question and include the relevant code. You might want to read this first: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)